# What is the difference between UUID is passed as string and also as UUID?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, janusgraph

For both the cases I am getting the same result.But my property is an UUID not a string.

```
    gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').has('provinceId','06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d').valueMap()

==>{name=[GVK One], location=[POINT (78.4486 17.4195)], type=[campaignSite], provinceId=[06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d]}

gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','city').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').has('provinceId','06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d').valueMap(true)


gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','city').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').has('provinceId',UUID.fromString('06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d')).valueMap(true)
==>{label=Province, id=942092344, name=[GVK One], location=[POINT (78.4486 17.4195)], type=[campaignSite], provinceId=[06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d]}
```

query with valueMap(true):

```
gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').has('provinceId','06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d').valueMap(true)
==>{label=Province, id=942092344, name=[GVK One], location=[POINT (78.448617.4195)], type=[campaignSite], provinceId=[06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d]}
```

Comment: could you please show the result using `valueMap(true)` in all your examples (i.e. use it in the first two queries as you did the last)?

Comment: Okay,the first query result is shown using valueMap(true).

Comment: do you have an index on "provinceId"? if so, how is that property key defined in your schema?